# Signs involved in suspension of algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

I have a question that seems almost too trivial to ask, yet it confuses me often.

Suppose now that we have a dg-algebra $(A,m,d)$ with multiplication $m: A \otimes A \longrightarrow A$. If we look at its suspension $(sA,d)$, which signs appear in the suspended multiplication
$$ m^{sA} : sA \otimes sA \longrightarrow sA$$
I know $m^{sA}$ is not a dg map as it has degree $1$. However, in the interpretation of the suspension $sA$ as the tensor product $\mathbb{K}s \otimes A$ for $s$ a degree $1$ element, we have that
$$m^{sA} : sA \otimes sA \cong \mathbb{K}s \otimes \mathbb{K}s \otimes A \otimes A \longrightarrow \mathbb{K} s \otimes A$$
which comes with a sign because of the shuffle $m^{sA}(sa, sb) = (-1)^{|a|}s m(a,b)$ , but is this the only sign or does the isomorphism $\mathbb{K}s \otimes \mathbb{K}s \cong \mathbb{K}s$ also come with a sign? Is it $-1$?

Comment: It does not really matter, as the only important property you want to check is that $\mu$ is anti-associative: $\mu(1,\mu) +\mu(\mu,1) = 0$. A global sign will not modify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter *too much*. One of the reasons that the shifted product on $sA$ is defined the way it is defined is that the unique extension of the map

$$\mu : sA\otimes sA\to sA$$

to a coderivation $d_2$ of $BA = T^c(s\overline{A})$ squares to zero. The reason it squares to zero is that $\mu$ is *anti-associative*, and you can do a computation to check this, which only depends on correctly using the braiding on $s$ and $a$, plus the fact $\mu$ is of degree $-1$. The sign will change things when $A$ itself has a differential, which then induces
$$\delta : sA\to sA \qquad \delta(sA) = -sd_A(a)$$
and a unique coderivation $d_1$ on $BA$.

The sign will then determine if you want $d_{BA} = d_1-d_2$ or $d_{BA} = d_1+d_2$, i.e. if $d_1$ and $d_2$ commute or anti-commute. Putting no sign makes them anti-commute, putting a sign makes them commute.

Comment: dear Pedro, thanks again for answering! Relating it to the bar complex is indeed an interesting take and what I was aiming at